# Elixir - concat and match combination

Tags: elixir

Elixir noob here. Trying to understand the basics through the official docs, I stumbled upon a piece of code which I don't quite understand and couldn't find a way to explicitly search this.

```
iex> "he" <> rest = "hello"
"hello"
iex> rest
"llo"
```

Source : https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html

What I don't understand is how the combination of operators worked and how rest got assigned the remaining string after a pattern match with "he". I tried to understand using precedence by putting parenthesis as follows :

Case 1 - Which was obviously not the same

```
iex(1)> "he" <> (rest = "hello")
"hehello"
iex(2)> rest
"hello"
```

Case 2 - Which looked the same but I still did not understand how it worked.

```
iex(1)> ("he" <> rest) = "hello"
"hello"
iex(2)> rest
"llo"
```

I did not understand because rest is undefined here initially and this worked more like the following code which is what preceded in the docs before the example mentioned above.

```
iex(1)> <<"he", rest :: binary >> = "hello"
"hello"
iex(2)> rest
"llo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"he" <> rest` here is a *pattern* and it's syntactic sugar for `<<"he", rest::binary>>`.

If you meant you don't understand how that pattern works, it's described in detail [here](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html#id67657).

In short, the pattern is parsed as the literal "he" followed by 0 or more bytes. `rest` is assigned to the rest of the bytes by this pattern.

The `binary` type is only allowed at the end of the pattern so the following won't work: `"he" <> ll <> "o"` (or `<<"he", ll::binary, "o">>`).